# What is ERR_CACHE_DOOM_FAILURE in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cache

I was looking through `chrome://network-error` page, and I came across the error `ERR_CACHE_DOOM_FAILURE`.  I am wondering what that means and what it is used for because google turns up no relevant results (the top result is about Doom, the game). I have also never seen this error in the wild. The direct link for me is `chrome://network-error/-412`.

Version:

```
Google Chrome:       111.0.5563.118 (Official Build) (64-bit) 
Revision:            93dbd66f6582b10ef120c5d62432cbc42a7bbcf3-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#1219}
Platform:            15329.59.0 (Official Build) stable-channel octopus
Firmware Version:    Google_Fleex.11297.296.0
ARC:                 9711795 SDK Version 30
JavaScript:          V8 11.1.277.17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This French
[article](https://www.gladir.com/SOFTWARE/GOOGLECHROME/reference-des-codes-d-erreurs.htm)
explains the error code as follows (translated to English):

> ERR_CACHE_DOOM_FAILURE : -412 : This error permits to indicate a failure of the destruction of the cache

This seems like an internal error, which I would guess would happen
when Chrome is closing down and is emptying its cache.
It should be an extremely rare error, up to impossible except
for memory corruption, and could be ignored by the user, even if
at all noticed.